# Iterate over array which includes objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am wondering how can I view different objects within an object using ng-repeat?

This is the following code that I have so far, to iterate over the $ID of the objects in array:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages"> {{message.$id}} </div>
```

This is how my array looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnHxO.jpg 
As you can see, the array structure looks like that:

--Item[0]:
-----$Id:xxxxx
-----Message1(unique ID):
-------------:date: "XX-XX-XXXX" 
-------------:message: "whatever"
-------------:sender: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
-----Message2(unique ID):
-------------:date: "XX-XX-XXXX" 
-------------:message: "whatever"
-------------:sender: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
--Item[1]:
-----$Id:xxxxx
-----Message1(unique ID):
-------------:date: "XX-XX-XXXX" 
-------------:message: "whatever"
-------------:sender: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
-----Message2(unique ID):
-------------:date: "XX-XX-XXXX" 
-------------:message: "whatever"
-------------:sender: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Etc.

TLDR: How can I use ng-repeat to repeat over the objects within an item of an array? Also, can I use ng-repeat to get the last object in an item? For example, the last Message sent?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried nested `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Honestly, I havent though of that.  Would it be something like ng-repeat="values in message", and then just {{values}} within the right div?

Comment: you can use some variation of nesting to achieve it.. for reference purpose, follow this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446253/how-do-i-properly-ng-repeat-through-nested-key-value-pairs-in-angularjs)

Comment: Nested repeats is the way to go however with the way your data is organized there is no easy way to distinguish between a message and the id or priority.  Consider transforming your data structure to add a messages array to your object and storing all the messages in it.  Then it becomes a simple nested repeat on the messages array.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my post. I've tried nested ng-repeat and it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention whether the items in your array are arrays or JSON objects. If you have an array of JSON objects then this will work

```
vm.objectsTest = [{$id : 123}, {$id: 234}];
<ul ng-repeat="o in vm.testObjects"><li ng-bind="o.$id"></li></ul>
```

If your items are arrays then you will need to access the object within the array, like this:

```
vm.objectsTest = [[{$id : 123}], [{$id: 234}]];
<ul ng-repeat="o in vm.testObjects"><li ng-bind="o[0].$id"></li></ul>
```

Alternately if you need to iterate over the items of your nested array, then you may need to have nested ng-repeats. However the best option would be to change your data structure as using ng-repeat excessively can create performance issues.

See this post for accessing the last element of ng-repeat
[Different class for the last element in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581658/different-class-for-the-last-element-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: Thank you emjrsoe for you answer! I've tried nested ng-repeat and it works with no issues.  Do you have any suggestions when it comes to restructuring my data?

Comment: If you have an array of JSON objects `[{$id : 123}, {$id: 234}]`, you can avoid the nested ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you! Have a greate one!