# ng-repeat show only last element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing inbox for messages with AngularJs, and I came across one issue: I want to show only last element within `ng-repeat`. I did some research, and found out that the code below should work.

```
<div class="inbox" ng-repeat="recipient in messages">
  <ul>
    <div> 
      <span> {{recipient.$id}} <br> </span>
      <li class="inboxItem">
        <span ng-repeat="messages in recipient"> {{messages.sender}} {{messages.message}} <br></span>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, it does not. Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong? I thought that `array.length-1` should limit ng-repeat to show only the last object in an array.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to use ng-repeat to show only one element?

Comment: My data structure is described in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166236/iterate-over-array-which-includes-objects  And its more complicated to do it without ng-repeat (at least with my set of skills)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

use angularjs `$last` in `ng-repeat`. here is [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="n in data track by $index">
   <span ng-show="$last">{{n}}</span>
</div>
```

`<span ng-show="$last">{{n}}</span>` when its last repeat `$last` will be `true` otherwise its `false` so you can use `ng-show` or `ng-if` with `$last`.

here  is a [sample demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U3Dnr6Ch99J9qcmavXlX?p=preview)

---

**UPDATE**
I think no need of ng-repeat there since you need to show the last element of the array (this is same as @Michael P. Bazos's answer), to do that:

```
$scope.data = [42, 42, 43, 43, 50];

print the last value as : {{ data[data.length-1] }}
```

here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rh7Ls8ZAuavBnmvh6YJy?p=preview)

but if you really need to do with ng-repeat do as this

`[data[data.length-1]]` create an array only with last element.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [data[data.length-1]] track by $index">
    <span>{{n}}</span>
</div>
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLAelYR7jHV23lQfHBN5?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome! It helped a lot! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You could use `limitTo` filter with `-1`

***Example*** :

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends | limitTo: -1">
    {{friend.name}}
</div>
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/5kxo9scg/1/)**

But if you are showing only one element, maybe you want to get rid of the `ng-repeat`... :

```
<div>
    {{friends[friends.length - 1].name}}
</div>
```

Comment: So I've implemented the "limitTo : -1" but it seems to have no effect on the data displayed. I am using ng-repeat, because my data structure required nested ng-repeat (each message in recipients has unique ID from firebase)

My data structure is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166236/iterate-over-array-which-includes-objects

Comment: Edit the fiddle with sample data as in your app, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: ADD: "limitTo: -1" indeed work on the outer ng-repeat, however it doesnt work on the inner ng-repeat.

Comment: Then the inner structure you are iterating over is probably not a collection

Comment: Turns out K.Toress answer works like a charm. Thank you for your help though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: simple, easy, and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
<div ng-repeat="something in vm.somethings">
  <span ng-show="$last">{{ something.value }}</span>
</div>
```