# ng-repeat eliminate duplicate objects in array and make the last pushed appended object preferred

Tags: angularjs

```
quizAnswers: [
    {"id":0,"Index":0,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"},
    {"id":1,"Index":1,"Answered":"No","Correct":"?"},
    {"id":0,"Index":0,"Answered":"Yes","Correct":"Correct"}
]
```

note the id and Index are the same on the first and last object

Given the array data above is there a way in ng-repeat answer in quizAnswers to make the last object override the first  e.g. avoid duplicate Index and Id's  and make the last item pushed onto the array the preferred object.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183476/ng-repeat-show-only-last-element) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks ;  however there will be lots of answer objects appended so I don't want to just display the last value  I  want the later objects to be preferred over their predecessors in the array    perhaps  quizAnswers.splice () on the controller side may be better