# Loop through the JSON file which has a unique ID with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have trouble looping a JSON file. Ng-repeat through the data array where each field has a unique id.

```
 var fullData = {
      data: [{
        505: {
          price: "505",
          source: "Amazon"
        },
        456: {
          price: "4555",
          source: "Jet"
        }
      }]
    }

<div ng-repeat="data in fullData.data">
{{ data[$index]}}
</div>
```

This solution dosent seem to work.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: cant you change this json strcture? different way..  i suppose to you change the  json strcuture like this
{
  data: [
    { 
   id:505
      price: "505",
      source: "Amazon"
    },
 {
   id: 890
      price: "4555",
      source: "Jet"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @rebello here is the mistake you have given  var fullData if you want to use it in view it should be scope variable first change this then try it should be $scope.fullData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.data = {
   data: [{
     505: {
           price: "505",
           source: "Amazon"
         },
     456: {
           price: "4555",
           source: "Jet"
         }
    }]
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.data">
         <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">
           {{v.price}}: 
            {{v.source}}
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $scope variable in controller to bind the data, change your code like this,

**Controller**

```
app.controller("DemoCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
     $scope.fullData = {
      data: [{
        505: {
          price: "505",
          source: "Amazon"
        },
        456: {
          price: "4555",
          source: "Jet"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div class="media-list" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat=" data in fullData.data ">
     {{data}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446253/how-do-i-properly-ng-repeat-through-nested-key-value-pairs-in-angularjs)**

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in comment dont use

```
var fulData
```

use

```
$scope.fullData
```

this will automatically bind the value in view

as you did

```
 {{ data[$index]}}
```

is not the way to access in ng-repeat data itself is enough to access as like this

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in fullData.data">
  {{$index}}
 {{ data}}
  </div>
```

here is js code

```
$scope.fullData = {
  data: [{
    505: {
      price: "505",
      source: "Amazon"
    },
    456: {
      price: "4555",
      source: "Jet"
    }
  }]
}
```

working demo  http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/yaEEyv