# How to ng-reapeat with multiple key values in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi i have object of multiple keys and values

The Response object has the follwing :

```
    Object
    MainID:"589d8ddaf7045b29b5101cdc"
    Url:Array[5]
    0:Object
        _id:"589d8ddaf7045b29b5101cdd"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720474060.jpeg"
    1:Object
        _id:"589d8e1d142ef52a4ffb8285"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720541230.jpeg"
    2:Object
        _id:"589d8eda142ef52a4ffb8288"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720730226.jpeg"
```

This is my angular code :

```
   $scope.data = response;
```

And this is my html code :

```
    <div class="add-pic-box1 col-md-3" ng-repeat="datas in data">
    <img class="thumb" ng-repeat="img in data.Url" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{img._id}}" src="{{img.url}}" />
    <span><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="close_img(data.url._id)"></i></span>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me please , thanks in advance ..

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: May be this link helpful for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446253/how-do-i-properly-ng-repeat-through-nested-key-value-pairs-in-angularjs

Comment: @Sajeetharan nothing will diplayed in the page

Comment: why is there a ng-model on the <img> ?

Comment: @Elamparithi.P check the answer

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with your ng-repeat , it should be, The child ng-repeat should have **datas** instead of **data**

```
 <div class="add-pic-box1 col-md-3" ng-repeat="datas in data">          
       <img class="thumb" ng-repeat="img in datas.Url" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{img.id}}" src="{{img.url}}" />
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('webapp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.data =  
   {
    "id": 5454554,
    "Url": [
      {
        "_id": "http://www.bcetupes.info/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/7194",
        "url": "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg"
      }
    ]
  } ;
 
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="webapp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="add-pic-box1 col-md-3">
    <div ng-repeat="img in data.Url" >
      <h1>{{data.id}}</h1>
    <img class="thumb" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{img._id}}" src="{{img.url}}" />
      </div>
    <span><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="close_img(data.url._id)"></i></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can you get this ID("id": 5454554,)

Comment: did it help to sort the issue?

Comment: i not have **Array object** for $scope.data , i only have object .

Comment: send ur email id i will send u teamviewer id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135368/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-elamparithi-p).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to get url data in one variable so you get only images.
check following example
 **$scope.data = response.Url;**

```
    Url:Array[5]
    0:Object
        _id:"589d8ddaf7045b29b5101cdd"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720474060.jpeg"
    1:Object
        _id:"589d8e1d142ef52a4ffb8285"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720541230.jpeg"
    2:Object
        _id:"589d8eda142ef52a4ffb8288"
        url:"images/product_images/file-1486720730226.jpeg"**
```

Comment: try this one  <div class="add-pic-box1 col-md-3" ng-repeat="datas in data">          
       <img class="thumb" ng-repeat="img in datas.Url" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{img.id}}" src="{{img.url}}" />